# Spring Boot REST API 401 on public endpoint?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting `401 Unauthorized` on not secured endpoint responsible for registering:

this is my Config class I use:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
//@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(
            new AntPathRequestMatcher("/public/**")
    );
    private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationProvider provider;

    SecurityConfig() {
        super();
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        System.out.println("XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        //this.provider = requireNonNull(provider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(provider);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring().requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
                // authenticated
                .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(provider)
                .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable()
                .httpBasic().disable()
                .logout().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    TokenAuthenticationProvider tokenAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    TokenAuthenticationFilter restAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter = new TokenAuthenticationFilter(PROTECTED_URLS);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler());
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler() {
        final SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
        successHandler.setRedirectStrategy(new NoRedirectStrategy());
        return successHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Disable Spring boot automatic filter registration.
     */
    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean disableAutoRegistration(final TokenAuthenticationFilter filter) {
        final FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
        registration.setEnabled(false);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new HttpStatusEntryPoint(FORBIDDEN);
    }
}
```

So for now I have public endpoints responsible for registering and login, but I cannot access them via Postman and browser.
Is something wrong with implementing this config class? What can cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `configure(WebSecurity web)` for publicly accessible endpoints, it will not apply the security filter chain for specified endpoints.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
          .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/public/**")
    }
```

OR Try to change the order for `configure(final HttpSecurity http)`. Add `.requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)` before the filters and entrypoint.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
        .authenticated()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
        .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authenticationProvider(provider)
        .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .formLogin().disable()
        .httpBasic().disable()
        .logout().disable();
    }
```